# How does one check why/reason my scripts are getting queued in slurm?

Tags: slurm

I am using slurm and I am getting trying to figure out why my script is not running/why its getting queued. According to me there should be enough resources to run but slurm doesn't agree. How do I check this?

command ran:

```
squeue -o "%22i,%.12j,%.8u,%25R,%22b,%.7m,%6q,%6Q,%t,%V,%.S,%e,%l,%L,%M"
```

output:

```
JOBID                 ,        NAME,    USER,NODELIST(REASON)         ,GRES                  ,MIN_MEM,QOS   ,PRIORI,ST,SUBMIT_TIME,START_TIME,END_TIME,TIME_LIMIT,TIME_LEFT,TIME
1843_[21-32]          ,flatness_exp,me,(Resources)              ,gpu:1                 ,  3000M,(null),429490,PD,2018-07-17T15:01:12,2018-07-20T13:31:12,2018-07-20T13:31:12,2-22:30:00,2-22:30:00,0:00
```

---

but what resources? Memory? Gpu memory? CPU? GPU? what exactly, that what I want, **exactly what**.

Comment: What you are probably looking for is [sinfo](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sinfo.html). You can find information on the status of nodes there. (I use [a wrapper](https://github.com/tdegeus/GooseSLURM) around this command, as I usually don't see right away what I need to know from sinfo.)

Comment: Each cluster has its specifics, but your post presents very little of it.  What are the partitions available on the cluster, what are the associated resources? Could you at least post a complete output of `scontrol show job 1843_21`?

Answer (score 1):

In the output of the `squeue` command you'll find a field named `NODELIST(REASON)`. 
The code in parentheses correspond to the reason why your job is not initiated.

In your example the job cannot be executed because of *resources*. And if we check that code in the [`squeue` documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/squeue.html) we'll find that:

```
The job is waiting for resources to become available.
```

In that [documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/squeue.html) you'll find the description of the rest of *reason codes*.

Comment: but what resources? Memory? Gpu memory? CPU? GPU? what exactly, that what I want, **exactly what**.

Comment: Sorry, but that information is not given. If you had enough privileges, you may contrast the requirements of your job with the resources in the nodes (scontrol show node ...).